# C - passing json_t (jansson lib) as parameter (pointers)

Tags: c, pointers

In `function1`, I need to get the value of `jsonObj` that is set (correctly) in `function2`, but I'm having some pointer issues I think.
How should I pass parameter `jsonObj`?

```
int function1(){
    json_t *jsonObj;
    function2(jsonObj);
    char * output = NULL;
    output = jsonToChar(jsonObj); //output is NULL after this, so jsonObj is probably empty
    ...
    return (0);
}

int *function2(json_t *jsonObj){
    DL_MY_MSG myMsg;
    //here I set myMsg correctly

    jsonObj = myObjToJson(&myMsg);
    char * output = NULL;
    output = jsonToChar(jsonObj); //output has the expected contents from jsonObj, so jsonObj is OK

    return (0);
}

json_t *myObjToJson(DL_MY_MSG *inputMessage){
    //converts obj to json_t and returns it
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use correct function definitions (prototype-like).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make `function2()` taking `json_t**`. Otherwise, the assignment to pointer `jsonObj` inside `function2()` does not affect the address pointed in caller.

```
int function1(){
    json_t *jsonObj;
    function2(&jsonObj);
    // ...
}
int *function2(json_t **pjsonObj)
{
    //...
    *pjsonObj = myObjToJson(&myMsg);
}
```